# Emulating ASP.NET PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler, web-scraping

I have a crawler application which should parse all items from a Page with paging. Unfortunately the web site that my application crawls uses postbacks for paging. How can I get contents of second page programmatically  for following URL in C#.

http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/coldwell-banker-dikey-gayrimenkul/konut-satilik/istanbul-basaksehir-bahcesehir/emlak-ofisleri-ilanlari/3OWB4lkhYFs=/9wZEBZ-ivFgmrA3ENMCIfQ==/qh.BgsUoTK4=/GmMGgVD5Wcc=/GmMGgVD5Wcc=?sParam=3OWB4lkhYFs%3d&sType=9wZEBZ-ivFgmrA3ENMCIfQ%3d%3d&ListIsBig=qh.BgsUoTK4%3d&sortType=GmMGgVD5Wcc%3d&pageSize=GmMGgVD5Wcc%3d

I've tried posting __EVENTTARGET hidden field along __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: bad idea... better find some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using screen scraping techniques (See HtmlAgilityPack).  This will require you to read the response and reissue form posts to mimic what the user would do in a browser.  Simple request replays will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to pass __EVENTARGUMENT hidden field. And don't forget to set name attribute, as well as id attribute.